# Is it recommended to use Swagger editor generated server or client code?

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-editor

As Hugh Lauer said, when discussing the construction of the Pilot operating system: “If the same people had twice as much time, they could produce as good of a system in half the code.” so [Less Code is better Code](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/Classes/736/Spring2008/Papers/p30-lauer.pdf).

I am of the opinion that using Swagger editor generated code (or openapi generator) is a good idea. That also decouples the REST layer allowing you to switch it at a later point and let you focus on your core logic. Googling around did not show any signs of other people doing this. So, I wanted to know if it is a bad or good practice to use Swagger editor generated Server or Client code? Could someone please share their experiences or opinions with Swagger editor? Why would one write the same code (and test it!) that can be easily generated by a tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is good question.
In my opinion, creating REST server/client code is well defined, routine and non complex work, and looking from programmer's side, it needs strong focus while it is created "manually": in more complex interface designs there is risk of make some bugs or mistakes, which fixing can be time-consuming and not too easy.
So, using the automation tool like Swagger code-gen can prevent from wasting time and speed-up the development process.
On the other hand, the Swagger code-gen's auto generated code sometimes has bugs (I found them in C# generated code, in enum handling), so it should be prooved and fixed. Of course, these bugs are repetitive and well defined, so after creating several projects you will exactly know, what needs to be fixed and how to do it - and it will take relatively little time - probably much less than creating whole code "manually".
Finally: I agree with you, it seems to be a good practice.